# Makefile linking a file to a file that depends on another file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker-errors

I have a file test1.c which depends on test2.c, which in turn depends on libcurl(curl.h)
In my makefile, when I do
gcc test1.o test2.o,
while linking test1 to test2, it gives error - undefined reference to all the curl methods used in test2.c.

How do I make test1.c inherit all the dependencies of test2.c without explicitly having to do gcc test1.o test2.o -lcurl

Comment: you have to link like that, the .o files themselves do not have that info (MSVC has #pragmas that allow it on windows but I am not aware that any linux compiler does it).

Comment: Some command needs to link the curl library. You can do it after you built test2.o and link an intermediate object file that combines test2.o and the library. Or you do it the usual way when you build the executable. There is no automation that pulls arbitrary libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by "_test1.c inherit all the dependencies of test2.c_"? And why don't you want to add the library to the linking command?

Answer (score 0):

There are many little shortcuts that Makefile provides that make it easier to get the job done if that is what you are asking.

```
# $* = "test"
# $^ = all dependencies

test: test1.o test2.o
    gcc -o $* $^

test1.o: test1.c
    # GCC command
test2.o: test2.c
    # GCC command
```